# How do you fix a jQuery function that only fires on second click?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that scrolls to an HTML id when you click the relevant menu list-item `<a/>` tag. The problem is, the code only fires when you click for a second time.

Any ideas?

Below is a sample of the code:

```js
$(function() {
  // Desired offset, in pixels
  var offset = -87;
  // Desired time to scroll, in milliseconds
  var scrollTime = 500;

  $('#topnav a').click(function() {
    // Need both `html` and `body` for full browser support
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top + offset
    }, scrollTime);

    // Prevent the jump/flash
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#trustpilot">Our reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#what-our-customers-say">What our customers say</a></li>
    <li><a href="#policy">Why check your policy</a></li>
    <li><a class="orange-btn" href="#contact">Book today</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section id="trustpilot">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/grx1pem5/1. Create a runnable demo that reproduces problem

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow, and I realise that I didn't explain the problem correctly – apologies! If you follow this link and click on the menu, you'll see the problem is with the offset not working until the second click: http://whatpolicy.uk.w3pcloud.com

Comment: P.S. Just click past the holding screen!

Comment: Ok. The above code works fine! It was a problem with another bit of code.